# What preprocessor macros can't be defined?

Tags: c-preprocessor

I noticed that trying to define `defined` as a macro in C/C++ gives an error:

```
error: "defined" cannot be used as a macro name
```

This doesn't seem strange to me, since allowing the redefinition of `defined` would probably break `#if defined(...)`-like directives. However, It made me wonder what other keywords would give a compilation error<sup>1</sup>. I found that the [C++ named operators](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/C_002b_002b-Named-Operators.html#C_002b_002b-Named-Operators) also can't be used in a `define`, but I couldn't find a list of all impossible macros. Are there any other macros that cannot be defined?

<sup>1</sup> while (re)defining keywords such as `if`, or `int` are about the worst thing one could do with the preprocessor, doing so does not cause a compilation error. I'm looking for keywords that won't compile at all.

Answer (score 1):

Per gnu.org, "you may define any valid identifier as a macro, even if it is a C keyword. The preprocessor does not know anything about keywords. This can be useful if you wish to hide a keyword such as 'const' from an older compiler that does not understand it. However, the preprocessor operator 'defined' can never be defined as a macro."